# preg_replace all non-digit characters except the number between second and third slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Assuming the input string `/en/614/5d` or `/en/617/19`, using PHP's regex functions I would like to remove all non-digit (`/\D/`) characters, except the `614` or `617` between the second and third slashes.
I know I can use split or explode to split the string but I need a regular expression pattern to use with preg_replace to extract only the numbers between second and third slashes.
Thanks.

Comment: you don't want to replace the digit if it is 614 and 617 ?

Comment: if you need to extract that number why not [`explode("/", $str)[2];`](https://eval.in/841965)

Comment: @bobblebubble I don't want a array in return.

Comment: @marvel308 I don't want to replace anything in between second and third slash as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/^\/[^\/]+\/|\/.+$/','',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be better and simple I think

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $input_lines); //replace any non digit
```

Comment: You should (re)read the question: “ I would like to remove all non-digit (`/\D/`) characters, except the 614 or 617 between the second and third slash”